# How to bind a DataGrid to another class' list?

Tags: c#, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid. I want to bind it to a List, which is in another class. Can I say the following?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AnotherClass.Instance.MyList}">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDatagrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  CanUserAddRows="False"> 
</Grid>
```

And set the itemsSource programmaticaly :

```
MyDatagrig.ItemsSource = MyClass.MyList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an MVVM approach.

Use an MVVM framework (like Prism, MvvMLight) or create by yourself a class for all viewmodels registration:

> Locator.cs

```
   public class Locator
    {
        public AnotherClass Another
        {
            get
            {
                return AnotherClass.Instance;
            }
        }
    }
```

Add `Locator.cs` as an available resources for your view, so you can call your property setting the right `DataContext`:

> MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridBindingExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridBindingExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataGridBindingExample"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:Locator x:Key="Locator" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Another, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">

    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

> AnotherClass.cs

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    private static AnotherClass instance;

    private AnotherClass() { }

    public static AnotherClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new AnotherClass();

            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public IList<string> MyList { get; set; } = new List<string>
    {
        "one",
        "three"
    };
}
```